# how to add ''this'' inside the set Interval function on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have one setInterval function like this.Appear the result only on first window.how to include 'this' function inside the setIntervel .help me to solve my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
    var user ='<div><b id="mainbox" name="mainbox"><form id="fm"><p id="chat-msgs"></p><input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Type msghere..."></form></b></div>'
   $("#demo1").append(user);
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#mainbox',  function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
 setInterval(function(){
  $('#chat-msgs').load('real-auto.php');//its  appear only on first window .
  }, 900);
});
```

```html
<a>ram</a>
<a>ravi</a>
<a>ragul</a>
<p id='demo1'></p>
```

Comment: Thats JavaScript, not Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#mainbox',  function(){
    var that = this; // store the current #mainbox
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function(){
        $(that).find('#chat-msgs').load('real-auto.php');//its  appear only on first window .
    }, 900);
});
```

but, here you are adding some elements with an `id` repeatedly and you can not have multiple elements in an web page with same id.
so replace all `id`s with `class`.

#### html

```
<a href="#">ram</a>
<a href="#">ravi</a>
<a href="#">ragul</a>
<p id='demo1'></p>
```

#### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var user ='<div><b class="mainbox" name="mainbox"><form class="fm"><p class="chat-msgs"></p><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Type msghere..."></form></b></div>';
        $("#demo1").append(user);
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.mainbox',  function(){
    var that = this; // store current .mainbox
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function(){
        $(that).find('.chat-msgs').load('real-auto.php');//its  appear only on first window .
    }, 900);
});
```